# Can I update data from android.provider.Settings

Tags: android

Dear All,
Please tell me how to update data from **android.provider.Settings.Secure.**

Although I had read the description from android document: 
*"Secure system settings, containing system preferences that applications can read but are not allowed to write."*

If There is exist any technique to solve this problem. please give me some keywords.

Thanks for All,
Nguyen Dai Son

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to limit your application only to devices with root access then there are ways, there are plenty of apps in the Market that have taken this approach. But, to my knowledge there is no way of a developer creating an Android application that will run on all devices that can modify secure settings.